# How to Distinguish Object in Java Set

Tags: java, annotations, set, lombok, hashcode

Hey Guys I want to store objects in a Set .
But even if an object contains same key-value it's stored as a separate entity in the set

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
class HelloWorld {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
        Set<Custom> set = new HashSet();
        set.add(new Custom(1,"HEY"));
        set.add(new Custom(1,"HEY"));
        System.out.println(set.size());
        for (Custom s : set) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}

class Custom {
    private int a;
    private String b;

    Custom(int a,String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "a : " + Integer.toString(a) + "b : " + b;
    }

}
```

Prints

```
Hello, World!
2
a : 1b : HEY
a : 1b : HEY
```

Can anyone suggest ways to store this as a same object .
Does adding annotation of `@EqualsAndHashCode` works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that annotation works. If you don't override `equals()` or `hashCode()` methods, objects are only equal when they refer to the same object instance. This Lombok annotation can generate the two methods automatically. You can also exclude fields using `transient` modifier or `@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude`. Read [this article](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the equals method.

See here for details: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-equals-method-in-java/

in your Custom class you would write a method called equals and use the @Override annotation:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {

    // If the object is compared with itself then return true 
    if (o != null && o.a == this.a && o.b == this.b) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;...
```

This will cause a collision when you add two objects with matching a and b values, thus preventing it from being added to the set again.

Comment: Normally you should check `o` to be non-null before comparing, otherwise `NullPointerException` may be thrown, which is not consistent with the standard.

Comment: This is a valid point. I was going for brevity, but in this case it would have been better to write the whole thing out